# Custom Text for Reply Action - Mirror API

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I am adding a reply action as a menu item to a timeline card.  I want to display custom text instead of "REPLY".  I use the code below and still get "REPLY".  Strange thing is if I go to the glass playground and just update the card(without ANY changes) it then shows the custom text.  Also if I update the card the menu displays the correct custom text.  Any ideas??

```
TimelineItem card=new TimelineItem();
List<MenuItem> menuItems=new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
List<MenuValues> menuValues=new ArrayList<MenuValue>();
menuValues.add(new MenuValue().setDisplayName("My Text"));
menuItems.add(new MenuItem().setAction("REPLY").setValues(menuValues));
card.setMenuItems(menuItems);
```

Answer (score 2):

The MenuItem values are documented as only being used for the CUSTOM menu item. See https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline for details.

This seems like a reasonable request to me, however. I suggest you file a feature request, giving as much of a detailed use case as possible, at https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/entry?labels=Type-Enhancement

Comment: At least they confirmed this to work when I asked during the I/O session, and I've seen applications that successfully make use of this feature.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying now (and I see where it is documented) - I missed that it was making the change on update, but not on original creation. Sounds like you should open this as a bug.